# Windows exception handling

Tags: winapi, exception

I'm trying to figure out whether using Window's
`SetUnfilteredExceptionHandler` will catch every exception in the process, or whether `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` will catch it before.

It seems that MSDN doesn't provide any info about the priority or the order of execution.

Comment: what is the sense of all this ?

Comment: *"How can I optimise my complex program that you cannot see?"*

Comment: You haven't explained the problem you are trying to solve. The entire question explains your solution, but we have no idea, what the problem is.

Comment: `VectoredHandler` from `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` called before `lpTopLevelExceptionFilter` from `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, before any SEH handlers

Comment: first called vectored handlers, than SEH handlers and the last routine from SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Answer (score 3):

the first is called [Vectored Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420(v=vs.85).aspx) (`VEH`)

> Vectored handlers are called in the order that they were added, after
>   the debugger gets a first chance notification, but **before the system
>   begins unwinding the stack**.

then (*if exception not handled*) called [Frame-based Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679353(v=vs.85).aspx) (`SEH`)

the last (top level) exception handler in `SEH` can be supersede by [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Enables an application to supersede the top-level exception handler of
>   each thread of a process.

`lpTopLevelExceptionFilter` is called last